# Using a record to choose a field to update a query shows a popup

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
UPDATE tblInstance 
(INNER JOIN Master_Table ON tblInstance.[WorkOrder] = Master_Table.[Work_Order_number])
INNER JOIN tblCustomer_New ON Master_Table.[Customer_Name] = tblCustomer_New.[Customer_Name] 
SET tblInstance.to_test_date = [Master_Table].[tblCustomer_New.Inital_Invoice];
```

I use a record from one table to choose a field in another table to update a record in a third table. I have all the table relationships set within Access.

Edit:
A value box pops up when trying to run it. It isn't pulling any data from the master table.

Comment: Sample data? Explain what problem you have with the query above?

Comment: It pops up a value box when trying to run it. It isn't pulling any data from the master table.

Comment: I don't understand anything about your problem (because you don't really explain anything) but if you want to refer to a value in a field you need to refer to it by using fieldname.Value, otherwise you will get a pop up box.

Comment: Ok I am not explaining this well. My set statement SET tblInstance.to_test_date = Master_Table.[(SELECT tblCustomer_New.Inital_Invoice WHERE tblCustomer_New.Customer_Name = Master_Table.Customer_Name)] does not work. When replacing the select statement with a field name it works. when trying to run it this way it give me the error " is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and this it is not to long.

Answer (score 0):

When MS Access does not find a certain identifier in your query it shows a value box asking for the value. See: [Why does Access want me to enter a parameter value?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Why-does-Access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-a7344543-e758-4785-8433-420eb0f0b48e)

To solve this you can take the following steps:

- Look at the parameter name it is asking for; it could be that the column name or a table name is incorrectly written. If you see an incorrect name which is not in the database, fix it.
- Otherwise try the same query but as a `select` statement:

  ```
  SELECT *
   FROM tblInstance 
  (INNER JOIN Master_Table ON tblInstance.[WorkOrder] = Master_Table.[Work_Order_number])
  INNER JOIN tblCustomer_New ON Master_Table.[Customer_Name] = tblCustomer_New.[Customer_Name];
  ```
- And then try just the subqueries, starting with, for example:

  ```
  SELECT *
   FROM tblInstance 
  (INNER JOIN Master_Table ON tblInstance.[WorkOrder] = Master_Table.[Work_Order_number])
  ```